# Meteor JavaScript - Error Handling

Tags: javascript, meteor, error-handling, server

In an HTML form, I have an input field. I need the value of the input to be what I decide it to be. E.g. I want the value to be only "abc". If the user writes anything else in the field, then he/she should get an alert/warning/pop-up **from the server**. How can I code this in **Meteor's JavaScript?**

Comment: What do you mean **from the server**? The content of pop-up is get from database or server side generated you mean? The pop-up as it self is a client side code.

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_error

Answer (score 0):

Use Meteor method calls: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods

On the server side:

```
Meteor.methods({
  "is-secret-valid": function (secret) {
    return {
      isValid: (secret === "123")
    }
  },
});
```

And on the client side:

```
myFunc() {
  let secret = ... // get input field from UI
  Meteor.call("is-secret-valid", secret, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      // Meteor failed to call, handle error
      return;
    }
    let isValid = result.isValid; 
    {...}
  });
}
```